# Timestamp does not match after reading date in ISO 8601

Tags: perl, iso

I have the date as "May 15, 2014, 5:39 AM" which I am reading in ISO 8601 and writing to other place
My code is

```
my $dcCreated = "2014-05-15T05:39:54.864Z";
my $iso8601 = DateTime::Format::ISO8601 -> new;
my $dt = $iso8601->parse_datetime( $dcCreated );
my $dayofmonth = $dt->strftime("%d");
$dayofmonth =~ s/^0//;
my $hour = $dt->strftime("%I");
$hour =~ s/^0//;
my $commentDate = $dt->strftime("%b " . $dayofmonth . ", %Y, " . $hour . ":%M %p");
```

which returns the value as "May 15, 2014, 9:39 AM "

Looks like it is returning in DST GMT format, which is four hours ahead.
How can I correct the GMT offset to get the result date to match with the original one.

Comment: There's no such thing as "DST GMT"; GMT (more properly UTC) is not subject to Daylight Saving Time. What is your local time zone?

Comment: When I grab the first 3 lines of your code and add `say $dt->strftime("%a %Y-%m-%d %T %Z");`, I get `Thu 2014-05-15 05:39:54 UTC`, which seems correct. And when I run your entire chunk of code, I get `May 15, 2014, 5:39 AM`, which also seems correct. I'm using Perl 5.14.2 and DateTime::Format::ISO8601 version 0.08. The code you show doesn't print anything; I suggest updating it to a complete self-contained program.

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamp in GMT so the code is correct. "2014-05-15T05:39:54.864Z": the trailing Z means Zulu time aka. GMT.

Zulu time: http://www.navy.mil/navydata/questions/zulutime.html

> Unfortunately the Earth does not rotate at exactly a constant rate.
>   Due to various scientific reasons and increased accuracy in measuring
>   the earth's rotation, a new timescale, called Coordinated Universal
>   Time (UTC), has been adopted and replaces the term GMT.
>
> The Navy, as well as civil aviation, uses the letter "Z" (phonetically
>   "Zulu") to refer to the time at the prime meridian.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

> Combined date and time in UTC:    2014-05-25T16:45:49+00:00 or
>   2014-05-25T16:45:49Z

Comment: In that case I want to add the offset of -0400 to "2014-05-14T19:30:26.086Z" so that the converted date results me:"May 14, 2014, 3:30 PM " i.e. it should be four hours behind. PLEASE HELP, HOW IT CAN BE DONE